# Using GIS data with CGAL

Tags: shapefile, polygon, cgal

I read a few posts here at GIS.SE that points to useful algorithms in CGAL. I'd like to test algorithms in CGAL such as medial axis transformation/polygon skeleton extraction, but the examples on the CGAL website are using text files or eps for input/output.

And I am just wondering what's the best way to use shapefiles and other common GIS formats in CGAL?

For example, can I convert polgon shapefiles to a common data format that CGAL reads/writes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to check out [SFCGAL](http://www.sfcgal.org), a wrapper library for CGAL that exposes CGAL functionality in terms of OGC Simple Features.  If you load your shapefiles into PostGIS, you can call many SFCGAL operations directly - there's a list in the [PostGIS docs](http://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#reference_sfcgal).